# Noun Phrase - complement vs. postmodifier

Tags: english, grammar, writing

Let's look at these two noun phrases:
1 - The chapter of the book.
2 - A mother of two kids.

Could you please help me understand why 'of the book' is a postmodifier while 'of two kids' is a complement?

Many thanks in advance!
Houcine

Comment: Who gave those definitions of those phrases?

Comment: Who says there is a modifier here? Both are complements if you ask me, since both nouns inherently describe relations.

Comment: I agree, both are complements.

Comment: Yes, both _of_ PPs are complments.

Comment: Hello everyone. Thank you so much for the clarifications. I found this in the Cambridge Grammar of English and I was so confused. Why would they consider 'OF THE BOOK' in 'THE FIRST CHAPTER OF THE BOOK' a POSTMODIFIER; and 'OF THREE CHILDREN' in 'A MOTHER OF THREE CHILDREN' as a complement. Source: Cambridge Grammar of English, CUP 2006, p 324

Comment: The Cambridge Grammar of English (Carter and McCarthy is an extremely confused and contradictory mess, with some allegiance to Halliday and to Quirk. Rodney Huddleston reviewed it in the journal English Language and Linguistics, and he very politely excoriated it as the most self-contradictory and theoretically confused work he had ever seen. Best avoided!

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. I was extremely confused when I read it. I was about to buy it :) but now I guess I'm going to buy Huddleston's book. Thank you again and have a blessed day!